# Nested routes authentication in NextJs

Tags: javascript, next.js

Is there any way we can Authenticate all the nested routes ? 
In my project I have routes which needs authentication and routes which can be accessible without authentication. 
For eg. 
/admin => needs authentication 
/admin/posts => needs authentication 
/admin/posts/1 => needs authentication 
/admin/users => needs authentication 
and so on.. 
/view => can access without authentication 
/view/songs => can access without authentication 
/view/posts => can access without authentication 
Things which I have tried : 
HOC : need to include it in every route I create inside admin. Is there any way we can do it in common place ? 
getServerSideProps : same as above

is there any way to do this in one common file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in multiple ways, just a couple of inputs :

If you are using next >= 13 with the new [app directory](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/fundamentals)  routing convention you can use the `layout.js` file in the root of `/admin` folder :

```
   export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
      // your logic to  check if the user is logged 
      if(/* user is logged */){
          return (
            <html>
              <head></head>
              <body>{children}</body>
            </html>
          )
      }else{
          return <p>Must be authenticated</p> // show login?
      }
    }
```

Otherwise you can use a similar logic inside the `_App.js`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import {MyAuthComponent} from 'auth/path' // your login component

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    const router = useRouter();
    const currentPath = router.asPath
    const isPublicRoute = currentPath.includes('view') // your logic to check if the current route is public
    if(isPublicRoute ){
        return  <Component {...pageProps} />
    }else{
      return (
          <MyAuthComponent>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
          </MyAuthComponent>
      )
    }
}
```

And `MyAuthComponent.js`

```
  export default function MyAuthComponent({ children }) {
      // your logic to  check if the user is logged 
      if(/* user is logged */){
          return (
            <html>
              <head></head>
              <body>{children}</body>
            </html>
          )
      }else{
          return <p>Must be authenticated</p> // show login?
      }
    }
```